# How to update existing AWS-lambda trigger or its cft without rebuilding the lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have an aws-lambda that I can not except downtime even for a little time that it takes to rebuild the stack.

I want to update the lambda trigger by adding a new SNS trigger to it. How do I do that with aws cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html) for cli example.

However, best practice would be to use Lambda [Versioning and Aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/how-to-manage-versioning.html)

Create new version of your function with updated configuration, test it, pre-warm it, and shift traffic to new version without any downtime.